# Why did old school names have this format: Initial. Middle Name Last Name?

Tags: names

Why did old school names have this format:

> Initial. Middle Name Last Name

Examples:

- J. Robert Oppenheimer
- G. Gordon Liddy
- F. Scott Fitzgerald.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really about *language* so much as... uh, sociology I guess?

Comment: 'Old school names' - you mean 'American mainly male names'. Having the format _initial-name-surname_ or _name - initial-surname_ is a very American practice.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey OTOH, initial-initial-surname is perhaps British esp. turn-of-the-century? C.S. Lewis, J.R.(R.) Tolkien, G.K. Chesterton, T.S. Eliot, H.G. Wells...

Comment: @AndyBonner - True, British authors tend to use either their first name (ignoring any middle names), or just their initials (J.K. Rowling?).

Comment: @AndyBonner - Tolkien has always been JRR to me. I am decidedly mid century and am MJ Harvey, but I think I am a bit old fashioned. Our school algebra text was by Clement V Durell, an English man. I think it was published around 1930.

Answer (score 1):

No deep reason.

It is common for people in the the Anglo/American culture to have multiple given names, typically a "first name" and a "middle name". Most people use their first name for every day use, and reduce their middle name to an initial.  "John F. Kennedy" for example.

Some people dislike their first name (for individual reasons) and use their middle name for everyday communication.  But they preserve their first name in an initial in formal use.

So Julius Robert Oppenheimer disliked the name "Julius". People called him "Robert" in daily conversation. But in formal situations, he would use "J. Robert Oppenheimer"

This pattern was always rare and exceptional.

Nowadays it is less common for people to use initials at all.  People who dislike their first name are more likely to choose a completely new name, or just ignore their first initial, even in fairly formal situations.

Comment: "Nowadays it is less common for people to use initials at all" —I *guess*, only because it's been awfully more common in past times. But there's still plenty, from J.J. Abrams to (perhaps) P. Diddy.

Comment: @AndyBonner - I sign myself 'Michael _X_ Harvey' (_X_ stands for my middle initial), and have been known to use the capitalised initial more generally, but I do feel rather American influenced when I do it.

Comment: Official use of an initial for the first name and a middle name spelled out in full is often not supported well or even at all by computers.  In my experience, it's actively rejected by the U. S. Government.  Some people have even told me, "That's not her official name," when something like M. Phillis Smith is offered.  I consider this view highly offensive, but it is quite widespread.  Shouldn't we all be able to use any of our legal, given names freely?

Comment: My bank insists on referring to me with a middle initial, but for myself I either use first-name surname, or (in suitable context) my initials CJF.  I agree with Michael that using the J with my names has an American feel.